# Delay in loading modal in angular application

Tags: angular, timepicker

In my angular application when i click on a button to open a modal the page crashes on chrome and on Firefox it will open after sometime with the warning as shown in the image below

[image]
I can see no errors on the console.
I was debugging the code by commenting one part after another and the issue disappears when i comment out the timepicker i'm using from [bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/timepicker/examples).

This was working fine till some days back .

I'm not sure what is the issue.

Can any one guide me here how to resolve this

**Update:On further debugging i found in zone.js the  drainMicroTaskQueue()  function is being called again and again.Any clue why this is happening?**

Comment: what does `the page crashes on chrome and on Firefox it will open after sometime` mean?, and that's just a warning

Comment: it means the application becomes unresponsive.The warning is all i have there are no errors which tell me what is causing the issue.

Comment: I would suggest to use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-bootstrap-modal

Comment: modal is working fine .I'm using it at other places also.